# Rails Poltergeist/PhantomJS not rendering www.example.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, phantomjs, poltergeist

### Background

Below is `test/integration/projects_test.rb`. We require a logged-in user to access `projects_url`.

```
setup do
  ...
  login_as @user
  ...
end

# PARTIAL SUCCESS (RENDERS LOGIN PAGE (instead of projects), IGNORES LOGGED IN @USER)
test "can visit projects" do
  visit "http://127.0.0.1:3000/projects"
  page.save_screenshot
end

# FAILURE (BLANK PAGE)
test "can visit projects_url" do
  visit projects_url
  page.save_screenshot
end
```

When I activate debug messages, it shows what's happening:

1. `login_as @user` is logging in to www.example.com.
2. `visit "http://127.0.0.1:3000/projects"` renders a page but it is **not** going to `www.example.com` so our `@user` isn't recognized as being logged in.
3. `visit projects_url` is going to `www.example.com/projects`, which Poltergeist/PhantomJS are rendering as blank.

### Question

So, how do I **either:**

- Get Poltergeist/PhantomJS to render pages on `www.example.com`?
- Move everything over to 127.0.0.1:3000?

---

### Resources

Contents of test_helper.rb:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'capybara/rails'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all

  require 'minitest/reporters'
  Minitest::Reporters.use!

  Capybara.default_driver = :rack_test

  include Warden::Test::Helpers   # Help with logging in and out.
end


class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end


class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Capybara::DSL

  require 'capybara/poltergeist'
  Capybara.register_driver(:poltergeist) do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {
      js_errors: false,
      timeout: 10,
      phantomjs_options: ['--load-images=no', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'],
      url_whitelist: ["127.0.0.1", "localhost"]
    })
  end
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
end
```

Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
end
```

Versions

```
ruby 2.3.1
rails 4.2.7
capybara 2.14.0
poltergeist 1.15.0
launchy 2.4.2
simplecov 0.14.1
```

---

#### A Request

Set Poltergeist to `url_whitelist: ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'example.com']`.

Run a test with `visit root_path`.

Result:

```
http://www.example.com/{"id":"1d9f77e2-c637-4097-bfa0-072f4371fcf6","name":"set_js_errors","args":[false]}
{"command_id":"1d9f77e2-c637-4097-bfa0-072f4371fcf6","response":true}
{"id":"983f046e-450a-4dcc-95f7-7f08caf1f059","name":"set_debug","args":[true]}
{"command_id":"983f046e-450a-4dcc-95f7-7f08caf1f059","response":true}
{"id":"e23a646a-fe9f-4e00-8d8b-dacce27d8c0e","name":"set_url_whitelist","args":["127.0.0.1","localhost","example.com"]}
{"command_id":"e23a646a-fe9f-4e00-8d8b-dacce27d8c0e","response":true}
{"id":"67d19849-60dc-4cbb-95d3-fef0e388fe2a","name":"visit","args":["http://127.0.0.1:52788/"]}
{"command_id":"67d19849-60dc-4cbb-95d3-fef0e388fe2a","error":{"name":"Poltergeist.StatusFailError","args":["http://127.0.0.1:52788/","Timed out with no open resource requests"]}}
ERROR["test_basic_poltergeist_test", ProjectsTest, 11.084383999999773]
 test_basic_poltergeist_test#ProjectsTest (11.08s)
Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError:         Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError: Request to 'http://127.0.0.1:52788/' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status - Timed out with no open resource requests
            poltergeist (1.15.0) lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:377:in `command'
            poltergeist (1.15.0) lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:36:in `visit'
            poltergeist (1.15.0) lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:97:in `visit'
            capybara (2.14.0) lib/capybara/session.rb:269:in `visit'
            capybara (2.14.0) lib/capybara/dsl.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
            test/integration/projects_test.rb:41:in `block in <class:ProjectsTest>'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:107:in `block (3 levels) in run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:204:in `capture_exceptions'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:255:in `time_it'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:103:in `block in run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:348:in `on_signal'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:275:in `with_info_handler'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:102:in `run'
            minitest-reporters (1.1.14) lib/minitest/reporters.rb:48:in `run_with_hooks'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:799:in `run_one_method'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:322:in `run_one_method'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:310:in `block (2 levels) in run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:309:in `each'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:309:in `block in run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:348:in `on_signal'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:335:in `with_info_handler'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:308:in `run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:158:in `block in __run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:158:in `map'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:158:in `__run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:135:in `run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:62:in `block in autorun'
```

Test.log (last few lines):

```
  Rendered shared/_searchBox.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered projects/index.html.erb within layouts/application (7.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.js.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 20.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
Started GET "/assets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-03 19:43:06 -0400
Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-03 19:43:06 -0400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow 'http://www.example.com' in your Poltergeist whitelist if you want it to allow page requests to that url.

Additionally, `http://127.0.0.1:3000` is most likely your development instance, so you don't want tests hitting that because it won't be using the test data you setup.

Comment: I tried doing that (changed `url_whitelist` to 'http://www.example.com') and I'm now getting gibberish returned from projects_url. Looks like '¾ïW˜ri]÷€S×V @âàÂ1kÜÕZ“”$í6¡÷ßqÛ½®åí@+µŽþlÇIžI“ûsPzUe‹äñ‡B'.

Comment: @sscirrus Look at your test.log and see what request is being made and what it's rendering in response, also I'm assuming you set `url_whitelist` to an array containing 'example.com' not just to 'example.com'

Comment: I'm still investigating, but test.log just has some queries that end with `ROLLBACK` (my local server renders it fine). I tried using `root_path` and `root_url` -  `root_url` takes me to example.com instead of my root. `root_path` is blank. To your second question, I confirmed I am using an array for `url_whitelist`.

Comment: set your poltergeist  `url_whitelist =  ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'example.com']` then try running with  'root_path`/`projects_path` rather than xxx_url - and if that doesn't work add your test.log to your question.  Also, are you sure your test is actually using poltergeist, and not just using the rack_test driver (which ignores the domain completely), and does `www.example.com` resolve to `127.0.0.1` on your machine?

Comment: I just added results of that test.

Comment: @sscirrus Increase your timeout to something like 120 (or precompile your assets for the test environment)-- your first test is timing out while your app builds the asset pipeline

Comment: I tried the 120 (still failed). I then ran `RAILS_ENV="test" rake assets:precompile` and after that, the test you suggested is failing with the same message. End of test.log is `Started GET /assets/twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff" for 127.0.0.1...`